# Bug: MathJax/LaTeX mathbb font in array

Tags: bug, math-display

I recently answered [a question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/635224/2958) using the following code

```
$$\begin{array}
\mathbb P\Big(X = \mu+\frac12\left(\gamma+\sqrt{4\kappa-3\gamma^2}\right)\sigma\Big) &=& \dfrac{\sqrt{4\kappa-3\gamma^2}-\gamma}{2\sqrt{4\kappa-3\gamma^2}(\kappa-\gamma^2)} \\
\mathbb P\Big(X = \mu\Big) &=& 1-\dfrac{1}{(\kappa-\gamma^2)} \\
\mathbb P\Big(X = \mu+\frac12\left(\gamma-\sqrt{4\kappa-3\gamma^2}\right)\sigma\Big) &=& \dfrac{\sqrt{4\kappa-3\gamma^2}+\gamma}{2\sqrt{4\kappa-3\gamma^2}(\kappa-\gamma^2)}\end{array}$$
```

and saw a difference in the $P$ and $\mathbb P$ at the start of the first line of the array compared to the second and third, looking like this trimmed image

[image]

In full

$$\begin{array}
\mathbb P\Big(X = \mu+\frac12\left(\gamma+\sqrt{4\kappa-3\gamma^2}\right)\sigma\Big) &=& \dfrac{\sqrt{4\kappa-3\gamma^2}-\gamma}{2\sqrt{4\kappa-3\gamma^2}(\kappa-\gamma^2)} \\
\mathbb P\Big(X = \mu\Big) &=& 1-\dfrac{1}{(\kappa-\gamma^2)} \\
\mathbb P\Big(X = \mu+\frac12\left(\gamma-\sqrt{4\kappa-3\gamma^2}\right)\sigma\Big) &=& \dfrac{\sqrt{4\kappa-3\gamma^2}+\gamma}{2\sqrt{4\kappa-3\gamma^2}(\kappa-\gamma^2)}\end{array}$$

What might have caused this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is that the `array` environment has a required argument that gives information about how the columns should be aligned, and in your case, the initial `\mathbb` is read as that argument.  The characters that are allowed for alignments are `c`, `r`, and `l` (for center, right, and left), plus `|` and `:` for vertical lines and dots.  Since none of the characters in `\mathbb` are valid, they are ignored.  But the effect is that the `\mathbb` is eaten by the `array` environment, and so it is not applied to the P.

Comment: So I should have started with something like `$$\begin{array}{lcl} \mathbb P ...`.  Fixed now.  Many thanks.

Comment: You can also leave the input empty like `$$\begin{array}{} \mathbb P` as long as you have the extra brackets